# Does "Hide Value" do anything on an Output socket? (Isn't it always hidden?)

Tags: materials, node-editor, interface, compositing-nodes, geometry-nodes

This is a really simple question. I was just wondering if a node's **Hide Valu**e option has any effect at all when it's for an Output instead of an Input. (This is found in the Group tab when editing inside of a Group Node.)

The following screenshot was taken within the **Compositor**, but this exists in **Material Nodes** and **Geometry Nodes** too.

[image]

I was wondering if it's for some planned future feature, or just a vestigial UI element, or if it actually does something I'm not aware of... because I can't think of any nodes that have sliders on their *output* sockets.

Just curious if anyone knows. Thanks.

Comment: Having a quick look at the implementation, the *Hide Value* checkbox sets the `SOCK_HIDE_VALUE` flag when enabled. There does not appear to be special behavior for the output sockets, as far as I could see.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Thanks. So do you interpret that to mean it was coded generically for any kind of socket, and the option was left available for *output* sockets too even though it appears not to make any difference for them?

Comment: That seems to be the case. The flag is checked in `std_node_socket_draw` (`drawnode.cc`), `uiTemplateNodeLink` and `ui_node_draw_input` (`node_templates.cc`), `gpu_uniformbuffer_link` (`gpu_unifirmbuffer_link`), `update_socket_to_match_interface` (`node_common.cc`), `matches_common_data` (`node_declaration.cc`), `node_socket_copy_default_value` (`node_socket.cc`) and `ntree_shader_unlink_hidden_value_sockets` (`node_shader_tree.cc`). In none of those use cases it seems to differentiate between input and output sockets wrt. the use of `SOCK_HIDE_VALUE`. I have only checked superficially though.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it says "Hide the socket **input** value". It is important - *Group Input* node has no input sockets.

If you made a group using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, then hide value:

[image]

In group node, you will see, that the input value field actually hides:

[image]

Output sockets always have no input fields, even in input nodes  (as you have already noticed):

[image]

In GN (in top node tree), this option seems to be useless, due to group node is not shown.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that it hides *input* socket value sliders (with the exception of a GN top level node tree). But my question is specifically about *output* sockets, for which it appears to do nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Output sockets are hidden, but this switcher disables input socket in the node outside the node group

Comment: @Crantisz What do you not understand? The "switcher" exists for input and output sockets, and the question was what are they actually doing for the output sockets. Saying they hide the input sockets doesn't clarify this.

Comment: It says "hide Input socket". Output is always hidden.